# Is there another style to make an \underbrace in big braces look elegant?

Tags: math-mode, equations, best-practices

I don't think the following equation looks good because of the existence of the `\underbrace`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
12\left(\underbrace{y^2 +2y\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) +\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}_{\left[y+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)\right]^2} -\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 +\frac{4}{5}\right) = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there another style to make an `\underbrace` in big braces look elegant? I want to pull the underbrace out of the braces.

Comment: You should really just use `\big`-like delimiters for the outer (all) brackets instead.

Comment: Related (i.e. `\smash` and `\vphantom`): [Changing the size of the braces from the cases environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126872), [ignoring vertical space due to overbraces in cases environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38930) and [Underbraces in Matrix Divided in Blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102460) (ignore the TikZ solutions). Though, in this case using `\big…` is of course easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `\left(` and `\right)` to auto-size the outermost set of parentheses, you could use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`:

[image]

(Aside: See the postings [Why the control sequences \bigl, \biggl, \bigr or \biggr, as I can always use \big or \bigg?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19480/5001) and [Difference between \big[ and \bigl[](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1232/5001) for a discussion of the differences between `\Bigg(` and `\Biggl(`.)

I would recommend, actually, using `\Biggl[` (while adding `\,` immediately afterwards) and `\Biggr]` to provide a bit more -- but not too much... --  visual prominence as well as variety to the outer fences:

[image]

The default LaTeX/amsmath style for underbraces frankly looks quite boring to me. If you have access to the [mtpro2](http://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package, you could use its macro `\undercbrace` to generate a curly underbrace. Cautions: (i) The font used by this package is Times Roman, which may or may not be to your liking. (ii) The `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge; however, its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed to use the `\undercbrace` macro, *can* be obtained without (financial) charge.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
12\Biggl[\,\undercbrace{y^2 +2y\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) +\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}_{\left[y+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)\right]^2}{} -\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 +\frac{4}{5}\Biggr] = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The immediately preceding example is intended mainly to demonstrate the shape of the "curly" underbrace. Thus, the only changes, relative to the code used in the second example, were in loading the `mtpro2` package and using `\undercbrace` instead of `\underbrace`.

If you're serious about using the `mtpro2` package, I would recommend making a few additional changes to the code. Chief among them are these: (i) load the `mleftright` package and execute `\mleftright` in the preamble to eliminate the extra horizontal whitespace that's otherwise inserted by `\left` and `\right`; (ii) don't insert a thinspace after `\Biggl[`; and (iii) insert a negative thinspace (`\!`) after the undercbrace material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
12\Biggl[ \undercbrace{y^2 +2y\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) 
  +\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}_{
   \left[y+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)\right]^2} \! {}
  -\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 +\frac{4}{5}\Biggr] = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add `\,` right before the `\Biggr]` to preserve the symmetric spaces? I don't like asymmetric properties.

Comment: @Marienplatz - I don't think it's *necessary* to do so from a purely aesthetic point of view; your sensibilities, though, may differ from mine... The reason why I inserted a thinspace after `\Biggl[` was to keep the bottom "hook" of the square bracket from touching the underbrace.

Comment: The space between `[` and the `y` seems to be a bit too much. The brace also interferes with the space at the end before the minus sign. I’d rather use the original brace …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - The example using `\undercbrace` was intended to demonstrate the interesting shape of the "curly" underbrace, and left the other settings, relative to the middle example, unchanged. I'll post a fourth example with the layout optimized for the capabilities of the `mtpro2` package.

Comment: not sure why, but with the `mtpro2` brace (and times font) the notation below the brace is noticeably farther below the main expression.  the extra space surely isn't needed.

Comment: What's the difference between `\Biggl[` and `\Bigg[`?

Comment: @mrc - May I suggest you repost your comment as a full new question? That way, more people will get to see it and to provide answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico I would, but I think I was being lazy before:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/why-the-control-sequences-bigl-biggl-bigr-or-biggr-as-i-can-always-use-b . . .